# C# to Java for android

Tags: java, c#, android, exchangewebservices

I am creating a program for android that will act as an email client. Problem is there is a specific type of protocol that doesn't work with Java, at least I haven't been able to find a way to get it to work. So, I have downloaded xamarin and am coding the methods in c# because this protocol is native to c#. My question is can I then somehow turn this c# code into a library or module that I can call from my java android app that will handle the methods that don't work in java using the c# code?

Comment: Q: ??What "protocol"??

Comment: You might be able to serialize and pass between with xml or json. Also, you might look into J# which compiles to the same thing as c# (if you are in the .Net framework) because then you might have your j# communicate with java. You could also create a Web API application in C# and send things through to android. There are a lot of choices, but none of them are really good.

Comment: Thanks @Bob I figured there weren't any fantastic options but for me to even be trying this in c# means I ran out of fantastic options a while ago. The problem I run into is will any of those things you mention work in android. Cause android is finicky about many things and I fear that J# may not work since Java VM and Android Java VM are different.

Comment: Android will allow you to instantiate normal java objects in your activity. The issue would be trying to get J# and Java to work together. That option was a stretch anyway because J# isn't supported any longer. However, If you use an API you can consume it with volley (see google volley for android) and it should be doable that way.

Comment: The protocol is native to C#?  What do you mean by this?  I have yet to see a C# API. executable or web service that cannot be consumed by some client not written in C#.

Comment: It's the Microsoft exchange web services. It is also available in java but the way it's written works in desktop java but not android java. To get it to work with Android would mean rewriting large parts of the library and that isn't a cakewalk.

Comment: You are confusing yourself, and people trying to understand what you are saying.  Microsoft Web Services are a set of web services which any code, written in any language that can make SOAP web service calls can consume.  You are talking about a MWS client, which is written in C# and has been converted to Java.  There is no "desktop" or "Android" version of Java.  Java is Java.  What you mean is that there are some libraries available on the desktop and not Android and vice-versa.  Your question is how can you use this library on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best route (being an android application) would be to consume a c# api with your java code. Other options include passing serialized objects through xml or json and trying to get j# to work with java to allow your c# to pass through IL to J# and then have that sent through to java.

Comment: BTW Bob: you, too, are absolutely correct.  It seems the "protocol" in question is [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), which is based on SOAP.  Here are a couple of alternatives for Android (short of hand-rolling SOAP messages): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28952/android-mail-client-using-exchange-web-services and https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api